# System info showing VESA even after installing the officical AMD drivers

Tags: radeon, ati

I've installed the AMD Catalyst drivers on 11.10 but still the System Info  window shows VESA. Is it still using the generic VESA drivers or is it just a bug ??

Comment: don't worry about VESA. It shows me too. check fglrxinfo | grep "fglrx vendor string" in terminal.

Comment: You can check your Xorg log file generated at /var/log/xorg.log to know which driver your Ubuntu system is using.